# How do I fix this assembly not found (UnityLinker.deps.json) error while building to WebGL?

Tags: unity-webgl

I'm building a project and this error appeared; it's the first time I'm building it to WebGL from unity. Any help is appreciated.

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (UnityLinker.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64', version: '3.1.7'
    path: 'System.Private.CoreLib.dll'
```

Comment: Can you create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example that generates this error? Starting from a new, empty project, what do we need to add to it before we can generate this error? Check any of the script libraries you're using, or any of the packages loaded from the Package Manager, or any script assets you've included from the Asset Store.

Comment: Hello @DMGregory, even building a new empty project gives the same error.

Comment: That's a strong indicator that your Unity installation may be corrupted in some way. Try uninstalling Unity and whatever code IDE you're using, and re-installing them. It would also help to edit your question to include information about your OS version. If on Windows, consider re-installing the latest .NET runtime too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DMGregory said it was something wrong with my unity installation, I reinstalled the unity editor and it worked fine. Thanks for the help!